# Why doen't val work on a cloned object?

Tags: jquery

I can't get it to work.

```
​<div id=​​​​​​​​​​​​"xrod"><input class="yrod"></div>
```

Why doesn't this line of jquery not set the value of the cloned input to 5?

```
var row = $('#xrod').clone();
row.find('.yrod')
   .val(5)​;

$('#xrod').append(row.html());
```

Comment: because there are a bunch of inputs, that are all being modified, this is just a snippet

Comment: @sje397 = doesn't work in chrome or FF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
var xrod = $("#xrod");
var row = xrod.clone();
row.appendTo(xrod).find('.yrod').val(5)​;
```

note that you dont need to append the html you can append a jquery object

Comment: this is what I was really trying to do, but you put me where I needed to go.

Answer (score 3):

common mistake

```
var row = $('#xrod').clone();
row.find('.yrod').val(5)​; // you think you change the value of the cloned object but you don't

$('#xrod').append(row.html());
```

you lack reference

```
var row = $('#xrod').clone();
row = row.find('.yrod')
   .val(5)​;

$('#xrod').append(row);
```

also you don't need to add `.html()` to row.